# Simple parallax scrolling doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add simple parallax scrolling to my website using [stellar.js](https://github.com/markdalgleish/stellar.js). The problem is that it just simply doesn't work; I feel like I've tried everything but it just doesn't work. I made this test jsfiddle because I thought it didn't work because it interfered with some of the other code on my website. But even on this test page on which I'm only trying to get parallax scrolling to work it won't work for some reason.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Jctk/4/

I'm calling the stellar.js library like this (as you can see in the fiddle):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.stellar();
});
```

Why isn't this working on either my website and the jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set the `data-stellar-ratio` for each separate element you want to scroll, and also you have to specify the pixel height of each element that scrolls separately.

Comment: I set data-stellar-ratio for each element and specified the pixel height of each element, but it still wont work. Would you mind looking at my new fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/5Jctk/12/. Appreciate your input.